# transforming R function output to match format of Python function output

Tags: python, r

translating a Python function to R I try to add more data while iterating through values which I split using strsplit() in R. The return value of the original Python function is a list of lists so this should be the same in the R version (vector of vectors). The Python function is

```py
anbaudauer = 12
planzen_list = [
                    'tomaten_6',
                    'karotten_4',
                    'paprika_7',
                    'erdbeeren_5',
                    'koriander_2',
                    'salat_3',
                    'zucchini_4',
                    'gurke_5',
                    'petersilie_2',
                    'radieschen_3'
                ]

def possible_combinations(values, target, with_replacement=True):
    def sub_combinations(index, l, r, t, w):
        if t == sum(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), l)):
            r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), l)):
            return
        for u in range(index, len(values)):
            sub_combinations(u if w else (u + 1), l + [values[u].split('_')[0], int(values[u].split('_')[1])], r, t, w)
        return r
    return sub_combinations(0, [], [], target, with_replacement)

raw_combinations = possible_combinations(planzen_list, anbaudauer)

# returns [['tomaten', 6, 'tomaten', 6], ['tomaten', 6, 'karotten', 4, 'koriander', 2], ['tomaten', 6, 'karotten', 4, 'petersilie', 2], ...]
```

the current state of the R function is

```r
w <- c(
  'tomaten_6',
  'karotten_4',
  'paprika_7',
  'erdbeeren_5',
  'koriander_2',
  'salat_3',
  'zucchini_4',
  'gurke_5',
  'petersilie_2',
  'radieschen_3'
)
n <- length(w)
t <- 12
D <- list()
for (j in 0:n) D[[paste(0, j)]] <- list(c())
for (i in 1:t) D[[paste(i, 0)]] <- list()
for (j in 1:n) {
  for (i in 1:t) {
    D[[paste(i, j)]] <- do.call(c, lapply(0:floor(i/as.numeric(strsplit(w[j], '_')[[1]][2])), function(r) {
      lapply(D[[paste(i-r*as.numeric(strsplit(w[j], '_')[[1]][2]), j-1)]], function(x) c(x, rep(strsplit(w[j], '_')[[1]][1]), r))
    }))
  }
}
D[[paste(t, n)]]
```

at `as.numeric(strsplit(w[j], '_')[[1]][2])`I would like to add the name of the vegetable before the number. In essence the R function should return the same as the Python function. Transforming the R functions return value was tricky so far. Basically I tried taking everything apart and stitching it together again. As I haven't used R in a long time I'm sure there is a convenient method to get the same data returned as from the Python function.

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorized.  You could directly use `strsplit(w, '_')` instead of looping

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with good old RegEx here? For a start:

```
#first drop the text before the '_' 
w_int <- as.integer(gsub(pattern = ".*_", replacement = "", w))
#repeat the replacement for the numbers at the end to get the vegetable names
w_names <- gsub(pattern = '_[0-9]*$', "", w)
#assign the vegetable names to the Anbaudauer-vector as names 
names(w_int) <- w_names 
w_int
tomaten   karotten    paprika  erdbeeren  koriander      salat ...
     6          4          7          5          2          3 ...
Anbaudauer <- 12
```

And from there on just check all combinations that add up to Anbaudauer. Potentially something like this ... [combinations of numbers to reach a given sum - recursive implementation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325979/combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum-recursive-implementation-in-r) don't want to repeat that here.

Comment: thanks, the issue here is that some plants have the same Anbaudauer (e.g. koriander and petersilie) and that plants can be reused. The suggested implementations gives correctly 103 possible combinations but I want to have the plant names included and not just the numbers that sum to the Anbaudauer as the plants are the distinguishing factor I'm looking for.

Comment: you can always access vector name attributes via the names() function; additionally the l|s|v*apply family of functions has a USE.NAMES = TRUE|FALSE parameter available, where the names can get preserved - in case you reuse the function in the linked answer; I think there are also package "purrr" functions that help handle this problem

Comment: but using ```w_int``` as input for the function does not get the correct result as it is ignoring that e.g. a plant with 2 days is occurring twice. Using ```w_int``` as input for the function results in only 50 combinations instead of the 103.

Comment: Hi ... have you tried using something like `combn(w_int, min(which(cumsum(w_int)>Anbaudauer), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: I am also not sure how you define correctly in your context - since you were originally asking how to split out names and numbers. The question has changed somewhat or is a different/new one.

Comment: BUT if you have all combinations defined as above `comb(...)` it is an exercise of applying something like this `veggies <- sapply(lapply(Combs, function(x) which(cumsum(x) <= target)), names)` to get the veggie names out PLUS removing the duplicates - serch for that on SO